# Show new value of computed property without refreshing in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, computed-properties

I am using Vue3 to develop the frontend part of a web application about films. In this app, the user has a list of those films he has already watched. To add a movie to the list, the user finds a film, goes to its profile and clicks on a button. After that, the add button is replaced by a delete button.

To implement this functionality, I have a created() method on my Vue component, where I inject the user list (composed of film ids) and the film. I also have a computed property which checks if a film is inside the list. In the next code snippet you can see the computed property **:**

```
computed: {
    filmIsInList() {
        return this.userList.includes(this.film._id);
    }    
}
```

In the template section, I have this HTML code **:**

```
<button v-if="!filmIsInList" 
v-on:click="addFilmToList();" 
title="Add film to list" 
style="border-radius: 112px;">
<font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-eye" class="fa-xl"/>
</button>

<button v-if="filmIsInList"
 v-on:click="deleteFilmFromList();" 
 title="Delete film from list"
style="border-radius: 112px;">
<font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-eye" class="fa-xl added-to-list" />
</button>
```

Methods `addFilmToList()` and `deleteFilmFromList()` are in the methods section of my Vue component and they make an HTTP request to an API I've developed with Express, to add or delete the film from the list, respectively.

The problem is as follows: The above code works, and when I click on the add/delete button, the computed property updates its value. However, I have to refresh the page to get the updated computed value of the property.

Is there a way to get the new value without refreshing the page ?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. That you have it suggests that the reactivity was messed up in some relevant place

Comment: It sounds like you're not updating the `userList` after you make the call to the backend. So, even though you have updated the value in the backend, your client side `userList`, which was fetched before you called to API to change the list, needs to be updated. The methods to modify the list need to ***a)*** trigger a re-fetch of the list; ***b)*** update the client-side list themselves (assuming all went OK on server) or ***c)*** return the new list contents and replace it on client side.

Comment: That's why it only updates when you refresh: you're re-fetching the list from the server. If you need help updating the list on client side, you'll need to show us more of your component code, namely all props/methods related to this computed. Specifically, `computed` works instantly. The moment you change `userList`, it will update correctly. But you need to update `userList` after you modify it on the server.

Comment: This is the key! I was only updating the list on the server side, not on the client side, so the computed property only recalculated its value when refreshing the page. Thank you for your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

While making an API call on clicking `addFilmToList()` or `deleteFilmFromList()`. On successful operation, You have to fetch the updated users list from backend again and assign the fresh response in the `this.userList`.

In that case, You no need to refresh the page again as you will have the updated users list.

```
addFilmToList() {
   // API call to add the film in the user list.
   // On successful insertion make an another API call to get the updated user list.
   // Assign the updated userList in the 'this.userList' variable or alternatively as you know the film is successfully inserted, You can add that film in the userlist at client side as well without making an API call separately (But this will not give you the real time response as suppose someone else add film for that user).
}
```